# UIImageView contentMode Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

hi every one i am facing a problem regarding UIImageView contentMode. i am using following code to adjust image in imageView.

```
CGSize imageSize=imageView.image.size;
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation=[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (imageSize.width>imageSize.height) { //land scape image
    if (orientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {  //device in landscape mode
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    }
    else //device in potriate moded
    {
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    }
}
else //potrial image
{
    if (orientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {  //device in landscape mode
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    }
    else //device in potriate moded
    {
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    }
}
```

code works perfectly when i call it in viewDidLoad method but when i try to call it in viewWillAppear method its not working. i want to use it in viewWillAppear, So please tell me the solution Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`?

Comment: image is not displaying properly. when i set mode to aspect fit image stretchs more than imageview frame. but if i use this code in view did load method then image get fill properly.

Comment: yes mundi i called it.

Comment: Is the relevant part of your code getting called? i.e. if you put 4 NSLogs in the 4 options (or breakpoints), is the relevant bit of code being called?

Comment: In my experience, the difference between viewDidLoad actions and viewWillAppear is that often I find in viewDidLoad that views haven't automatically resized at this point - so frame sizes etc aren't correct. By the time viewWillAppear gets called the frame resizing has happened. So I'm wondering if you're seeing a different behaviour (and a different bit of your code is being called) in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear?

Comment: thanks for the reply charles. i found the problem. problem was that i was not setting image after setting content mode. so its fixed now.